# How to efficiently overwrite the memory region on GPU?

Tags: memory, memory-management, cuda, gpu

I allocate the data block on GPU. And I have an algorithm to generate new data to replace the old one. The new buffer has the same data size. There is a solution is to bring the old data back to the cpu and then erase it but I think that’s highly inefficient and very slow. Is it possible to overwrite the old element with the new data at the same location?

Comment: If you can overwrite the old data on the go, then just `mydata[i]=mydata[i]+math;` Otherwise maybe you need 2 copies and use them as a buffer `mydataA[i]=mydataB[i]+mydataB[i+1]` and `mydataB[i]=mydataA[i]+mydataA[i+1]` alternating.

Answer (score 1):

If your kernels accept a pointer that's pointing to some buffer region, you may be able to just pass the original data pointer to that kernel, causing your input data to be overwritten by the results of the kernel.

Or if you're working with an algorithm that requires using a buffer, you could use `cudaMemcpy` to copy the results stored in the buffer to the region of memory holding your input data, overwriting it in the process.